# Set Heroku environment variable without restarting app

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, environment-variables

Is it possible to set a Heroku environment variable *without* restarting the app?

My app connects out to different online services via OAuth2. For each service I connect to, I need to set an OAuth2 ID and secret. To keep these configuration variables outside of my code, I'm using environment variables, and reading them in on `process.env` (node.js).

Each time I add a new service to my app, I need to add the corresponding environment variables for the ID and secret. I need to do this before pushing the latest code, so that when the app next starts up with the new service connection, the OAuth2 ID and secret variables are available.

Currently my workflow is as follows:

1. Set the environment variables using the Heroku toolbelt: `heroku config:set <SERVICE>_ID=foo <SERVICE>_SECRET=bar`
2. Push the latest code: `git push heroku master`

Currently, both of these operations will restart the app. I'd really prefer the first operation to not restart the app, as the changes to these config vars don't need to take effect until step 2). By restarting at step 1) my app will experience unnecessary downtime.

So, is there any way to prevent step 1) from restarting the app?

Comment: You cannot change environment variables for a running process. You could only manipulate it from within the app. But if you need to change a environment variable while the app is already running, you are doing something wrong anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but if you'll notice, I'm actually adding an environment variable, not changing an existing one. So I don't think this counts as 'doing something wrong'?

Comment: You are setting a service secret after the application is already running. A service secret is to me a configuration that should not ever change while the application is running.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. This is however a service secret for a service that has not yet been deployed. So it shouldn't impact anything else. What I'm really after here is for the deployment of a new service and the setting of the env vars for this service to be an atomic operation, i.e. one that only causes a single app restart.

Answer (score 24):

According to [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) it pretty explicitly states that

> Whenever you set or remove a config var, your app will be restarted.

Personally I also wish there was a way to do what you're asking.  On larger apps, a system-wide hard restart can be painful when you have many process types running.  Many times I set environment variables that aren't crucial for the app to grab ahold of immediately, such as that involving future functionality, or settings that are OK having the old value but you want the new value to take effect in a rolling-restart fashion.

Comment: Is this proposed to heroku ?

Answer (score 4):

At the present, is not possible to avoid the app restart. But you can use the command `heroku config:edit` to edit your env at once or even paste a new env set, avoiding many restarts.

In according to the heroku config help:

```sh
(...)

COMMANDS
  config:edit   interactively edit config vars
  config:get    display a single config value for an app
  config:set    set one or more config vars
  config:unset  unset one or more config vars
```

So you can run

```
heroku config:edit
```

Additionally, you might want to take a look on this issue (proposal):
https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1570